# Best practice for loading different themes or css files for different users in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, themes, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain

There are 2 questions:

1. How to do the routing for different customers under same domain e.g.
   For customer A the url looks like:   http://cusA.mydomain.com
   For customer B the url looks like:   http://cusB.mydomain.com
2. And according to different url(the above urls) to load different themes.

For question 1: I know we have sub-domain concept which talking about something more like :
www.mydomain.com/cusA and www.mydomain.com/cusB. 
So I don't know whether it is capable of doing the sub-domain in front of mydomain

For question 2: If the question 1 gets solved, then I think I could read and parse the url and loading different themes according to the cusA or cusB part by using ASP.NET MVC theme stuff.

Could anybody provide some thoughts and technologies to use in my case?

Thank you.

Update:

Tried to use "Request.ApplicationPath" but doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
<h2>Site 2 Home Page</h2>

<a href="/Home/Contact">Go to Contact</a>
<label>The Application Path is @Request.ApplicationPath.Substring(1)</label>
```

Comment: what you realy wanted is Multi tenant Architecture, may this link http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/ help you

Comment: hi @nikhilsreeni I think you point out the way I may need to go with. thank you

Comment: hi @nikhilsreeni I followed that article and it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not necessarily best practice, but rather how we have approached it in our product.

We have multiple sites running of the same application binaries, but each in a different application pool on the server. Each web-share has a config- and CSS file corresponding to the name of the share. We then use the config- and CSS files based on the Application's name on the server (i.e. Request.ApplicationPath).

In your case, you would have a web-share named CusA and another named CusB. You would have CSS files also named CusA.css and CusB.css respectively. You can then just include the CSS file based on the name of the application...

An example of including the stylesheet might be as follows:

```
<link href="<%=Request.ApplicationPath.Substring(1)%>.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

That will link to "CusB.css" if the web-share's name is "CusB". The above snippet needs to be included in your view as a style include, but the view engine you use would obviously influence the syntax a bit.

Comment: hi FarligOpptreden, I am still confused , could you please provide a simple example? thanks

Comment: huh, I think my case is different. the cusA.mydomain.com and cusB.mydomain.com are actually using same code base but just load different themes.

Comment: No it's exactly the same as my scenario - we have a multi-tenant solution with roughly 80 web-shares on the same set of binaries (code), so that should work. :)

Comment: hi thank you for your explanation :) I think I just feel confused about how to tell hosting server that cusA.mydomain.com and cusA.mydomain.com are under same website. I am grateful if you could share some code with explanation and even better if there is a demo. thank you.

Comment: You don't have to tell the hosting server that they're running under the same binaries, you just set up your web-shares that way: when creating the web-share in IIS, just make sure they all point to the same application binaries, but run under different application POOLS. You can then do the checks for different CSS files and config files based on the application name, as I explained above. You'll need to make sure your code is structured for multi-tenancy (dedicated config files for each share), as the Web.Config etc will now be shared by all applications under those binaries.

Comment: oh~~so it's some work in IIS configuration and some in coding. So the google search key word = multi-tenancy, right?

Comment: That's about it, yes. :)

Comment: Hi Farlig, I tried your way, but the Request.ApplicationPath is empty. Please see my update.